# Update Gallery Randomly in every hour with no duplicates?

Tags: pagination, infinite-scroll

I need to **order by rand** with no duplicates and **update** my galley in every hour on WordPress.

Check the code bellow. This is what I want, ( PHP , MySQLi ):

```
<?php
            include ("connect-sqli.php");
            $rand = date("g");   // Update Gallery Randomly in every hour.....

            $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY RAND($rand)";
```

**Q :** How can I do this on a WordPress site?

WordPress Code:

```
<div id="container">

          <?php if (have_posts()) :

                global $wp_query;

                $args = array_merge($wp_query->query, array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'orderby' => 'rand',
                    ));

                query_posts($args);
                $x = 0;
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;
                    ?>

                <div id="post-container"> Post Template Here </div>

                <?php $x++; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
           <?php else : endif; ?>

    <nav id="page-nav">
        <?php next_posts_link() ?>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You should never use `query_posts`, under any circumstances. If you want to modify a query, use the  `pre_get_posts` filter, if you want to create a new or temporary query, use `WP_Query` or `get_posts`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TomJNowell. I need to know how to add a random number in WordPress Codex. `'orderby' => 'rand(5,2)'` / `$rand = date("g");` `'orderby' => 'rand($rand)'` this codes are not working. I'm new to WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to retrieve a set of posts, and display them, in a random order.

Firstly:

- Indent your code to prevent bugs, as it reads, there is a closing `endif;` in your questions code but no if statement was ever opened. If you had indented correctly this would be trivial to spot, good editors will do the indenting for you automatically
- `$do_not_duplicate` is undefined
- Never under any circumstances use `query_post`. Whatever site or person told you to use it was mistaken, and it encourages bad practices that lead to common and easily avoidable problems, e.g. pagination issues

If you are trying to replace the posts listed on a page with a different list of posts that are randomly ordered, then you should use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the main query rather wasting time by throwing it away and putting a new one in its place.

If you're trying to add a list of posts in a sidebar or at the end of a post then use `WP_Query`, e.g.:

```
$parameters = array( ... );
$query = new WP_Query( $parameters );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    // posts were found
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        // set the current post, then display it
        $query->the_post();
    }
    // cleanup afterwards
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // nothing was found
}
```

The codex page for WP_Query contains a full list of all the parameters it takes and their usage, including `orderby`. Specifically it mentions a `rand` value to select random posts. These options are not SQL, so placing raw SQL for randomness inside it will not work, and is not advised.

If you wish to prevent duplicates, you should use `post__not_in` to specify which posts not to retrieve, but as you're trying to modify an archive or main query I don't believe this is of help to you.

Instead something similar to this should help:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'rand' );
    }
} );
```

That snippet will make all main queries on the frontend randomly ordered, you will need to add an additional check to make sure only the page/archive you want is ordered randomly, but since you haven't mentioned where your query is being made or why, I can only guess at that, but it might make an interesting new question

Comment: Thanks @Tom . But please can I know how to load next page with no duplicates. I have already adde 300+ posts on my site ( 5 posts per page ). `'post__not_in'  => array( $post->ID )` not responding. How to order **Random** without **duplicates**? Please help!

Comment: As I said, $do_not_duplicate is undefined, you've not told us where it comes from. Also, having randomly ordered posts with pagination makes no sense unless they're always ordered the same way, which means they'd no longer be random. Your comment does suggest however, that you're trying to replace a pages main query, so `pre_get_posts` is what you should be using, so that pagination still works.

Comment: Oh WordPress make me so angry..... WordPress codex so hard to understand more than php,mysql,python,ruby,js all other languages. I learned all other languages easily more than this idiot codex. Dear @Tom please can you edit your " code e.g: " in your answer and add a code to stop duplicates. This is a very little thing on PHP but like a big idiot world in WordPress.

Comment: The codex is being replaced by the developer hub at http://developer.wordpress.org, you can use `pre_get_post` to set the order to random, but the changing every hour part doesn't make a lot of sense and will be very difficult to accomplish. If you're aware of any place in the codex that recommends using `query_posts` please link me to it so that it can be ammended

Comment: Hey @Tom I fixed my issue :) appreciate your answer and all this comments.great man Thanks!